ошибка CS0246 на Unity
Я сижу на русифицированной версии Unity, делаю мультиплеер.
Вот мой скрипт:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MPMenu : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    void Start()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectToRegion("ru");
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        Debug.Log("Падущька присоединилась к игре падуська");
    }
    public void CreateRoom(string name)
    {
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions(); // Вот тут ошибка
        roomOptions.MaxPlayers = 10; 
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(name);
    }
    public void JoinRandomRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
    }
    public void JoinRandomRoom(string nameF)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(nameF);
    }
    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GamePoka");
    }
}

Он показывает, что ошибка находится в RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions(); в самих двух RoomOptions, хотя в документации и туториале написано правильно.

Это сохранитель вопроса в старой форме

using Photon.Realtime;

спасибо @MBo я сделал этот код

Ошибка CS0246 означает следующее: не удалось найти имя типа или пространства имен (отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку?)
Значит, в указанной строке используется класс RoomOptions, который не описан в текущем пространстве имён, неизвестен сборщику программы.
Находим, что для этого нужно добавить директиву using с пространством имен Photon.Realtime (т.е. указать, где именно описан данный тип)
using Photon.Realtime;

